# Running mvn -Pios client:link results in undefined symbols

Tags: gluon-mobile

I'm new to building iOS apps and gluon-mobile....

I'm trying to build the GluonMobile-SingleViewProject as created by the IntelliJ Gluon Mobile plugin v2.8.5. I have not made any modification to the generated code. The compile phase seems to complete without issue but when running the `mvn -Pios client:link` command I end up getting a lot of `Undefined symbol` errors. I think I have followed all the steps in the gluon-mobile document but I can't seem to get past this error.

Below is the build output from the failing link task.

```
INFO] --- client-maven-plugin:0.1.36:link (default-cli) @ gluonmobile-singleviewproject ---
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:11 PST 2021][INFO] ==================== LINK TASK ====================
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]   "_JVM_NativePath", referenced from:
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Get_From_Cache in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]   "_JVM_RawMonitorCreate", referenced from:
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Get_From_Cache in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Put_In_Cache0 in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]   "_JVM_RawMonitorDestroy", referenced from:
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _freeZip in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]   "_JVM_RawMonitorEnter", referenced from:
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Get_From_Cache in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Put_In_Cache0 in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Close in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_FreeEntry in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Lock in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_GetEntry2 in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_GetNextEntry in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       ...
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]   "_JVM_RawMonitorExit", referenced from:
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Get_From_Cache in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Put_In_Cache0 in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Close in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_FreeEntry in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_Unlock in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_GetEntry2 in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       _ZIP_GetNextEntry in libzip.a(zip_util.o)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB]       ...
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][INFO] [SUB] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[Wed Feb 24 22:02:15 PST 2021][SEVERE] Process link failed with result: 1
```

This is on macOS bigSur (11.0.1) running Xcode 12.4.

Any and all help appreciated.
Thanks,
Joshua

Comment: See your pom.xml and make sure you have the latest Client plugin version (0.1.38).

Comment: Thank you @JoséPereda that solved the issue!